# My page won't change when I change my React files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

Ok, so my code was working and all of a sudden it stopped changing the page when I changed the code, I am still in the beginning of the project, so I could just restart it, but I want to know why is that happening.
A sample below. Initially it was "This is the home page", and I changed to "Work, please" to test it out. Well, it didn't work at all. I already deleted cache files and tried to re-run the server (I'm using Django for backend).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import RoomJoinPage from './RoomJoinPage.js';
import CreateRoomPage from './CreateRoomPage';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class HomePage extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render(){
        return <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/'><p>Work, please</p></Route>
                <Route path='/join' component={RoomJoinPage} />
                <Route path='/create' component={CreateRoomPage} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
        
    } 
}
```

Comment: How do you build your code?

Comment: Well, I am just getting started with React (and Django), so I am following this tutorial on youtube, from Tech With Tim.

Comment: Did you update react version or react-script version? What is the current version that you are using?

Comment: Well, when I installed it I just used npm i react react-dom --save-dev. In my package.json I have informed the version 17.0.1

Comment: And version for react-scripts?

Comment: I didn't install react-scripts.

Comment: Have you set up your project to use hot reloading? That’s not automatic, you need to manually code that in, unless you’re using create-react-app, which it sounds like you’re not (which is totally fine)

Comment: Wow, that sounds good. But how do I do that? I did some research but I got nothing, could you recommend me a tutorial or something?

Comment: You need a watcher to re-build and pack your code each time you make a change. `webpack` and `rollup` can help you with this, I'd recommend `rollup` as it is easier to setup but is more limited than `webpack`.

Answer (score 0):

I started the project again (just the React part) and I realized I haven't run the command "npm run dev" that was a script I inserted in my package.json. When I followed the tutorial I realized the mistake and the issue was all about that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the order of Router components. You need to write main router to the end of the order:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import RoomJoinPage from './RoomJoinPage.js';
import CreateRoomPage from './CreateRoomPage';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class HomePage extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    render(){
        return <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/join' component={RoomJoinPage} />
                <Route path='/create' component={CreateRoomPage} />
                <Route exact path='/'><p>Work, please</p></Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
        
    } 
}
```